# org-cycle in Doom Emacs: 2 instead of 3 states

Tags: org-mode, cycling

I recently installed Doom and noticed that in org-mode the Tab key (used for local/subtree visibility cycling) only cycles between 2 states ('folded' and 'children') as opposed to 3 states I'm used to from vanilla Emacs ('folded', 'children' and 'subtree'). I can't seem to find the reason for that. Tab is bound to `org-cycle`, the documentation of which clearly mentions 3 states. Invoking the function "manually" through `M-x` never unfolds the entire subtree either. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you check to see if `org-cycle` is advised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Removing `+org-cycle-only-current-subtree-h` from the `org-tab-first-hook` list of hooks restores 3-state cycling:

```
(setq org-tab-first-hook (delete '+org-cycle-only-current-subtree-h org-tab-first-hook))
```